# does 'A' in 'Easy A' (movie) mean "ei"?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context, colloquialisms

English is not my first language. I have just watched the movie *Easy A*. I understood its content a little bit but I don't understand what the title means.

I often hear many Native English speakers put the sound "*ei*" after an adjective when they express the degree of an attribute of a certain thing, something like,

- '*it's easy ei*',
- '*hard ei*',
- '*cool ei*',
- '*she's good ei*',
- '*he's bad ei*' …,
  especially in Australia.

Does 'A' in *Easy A* mean "*ei*"?

Comment: That "ei" sound is transcribed into writing usually as "ey". Cool, ey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A" does not mean "ei" in this context, it means a high grade one gets in school. ("A" for excellent achievement, "B" for above average, "C" for below average", "D/E/F" for fail, depending on the school.)

The phrase "Easy A" is a common slang expression in the US meaning a subject in which one can get high marks without trying too hard.

Comment: but why there is "Cool A", "Bad ei" , in AUstralia they use a lot not just "Easy A"

Comment: @Kiti That's another question. :)

Comment: There is no relationship between the two things. "Cool A", "Bad A", etc. actually mean "Cool eh?", "bad eh?", it's just in Australian English the pronunciation sounds like "ei". It can also be written as "aye" or "ay". In the UK "innit" is often heard, and it has the same meaning.

Comment: @user43898, ur explanation is much clearer & that is what i want to know